# Image not saving with name in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```js
var dbs=firebase.database();
var stg=firebase.storage();
var inp=document.getElementById("filess");
inp.onchange=lasted;
function lasted()
{
  var fname=this.files[0];
  var btns=stg.ref("Gis/"+ fname);
  btns.put(fname);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="fileid" id="filess" multiple>
```

While I Upload the image and save it to the Firebase Storage. It is saving as **[object Type]**. How can I store it using the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`files` property of an input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) is a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) where each element is a [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). To get its name, use `File.name`:

```
function lasted()
{
  var fname=this.files[0].name;
  var btns=stg.ref("Gis/"+ fname);
  btns.put(fname);
}
```