# How to save an uploaded image to Google Firebase?

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to save an uploaded image in HTML to Google Firebase, so I guess I should store it in the Firebase storage? But how do you do that?
Here is how it looks like in HTML:

```
<div class="add-img">
         <label for="add-img">
              <img src="assets/dodajsliku.png">
         </label>
         <input id="add-img" type="file">
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
addImgFunction(){
                var dbs=firebase.database();
                var stg=firebase.storage();
                var inp=document.getElementById("add-img");
                inp.onchange=lasted;
                function lasted()
                {
                var fname=this.files[0];
                var btns=stg.ref("Posts/"+ fname);
                btns.put(fname);
                }
                }
```

And how should I use the reference of the recent image in js file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with only HTML. You can use Javascript to upload images/or files to storage. First you need to have a form in HTML, something like:

```
<form>
   <div class="adding-image">
         <label for="file-input">
              <img src="assets/addimg.png" id="uploadImage">
         </label>
         <input id="file-input" type="file">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="upload images" id="uploadImage" onclick="uploadFunction()">
</form>
```

Then in your javascript function- uploadFunction() mention your upload logic. You can refer the documentation from the link below for upload process.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestion how to use the reference for recent file/image? For example should I use: "this.referencename"?

Comment: I edited the answer. Take a look at img tag. I have added an id (uploadImage) to the tag. So you can get the image src by using `var uploadImg = document.getElementById("uploadImage").src;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609179/image-not-saving-with-name-in-firebase?rq=1 you can take a look at this question. I guess your questions are answered there

Comment: I tried with last example you posted, I used that function and I used @file.prevent instead of onclick and it shows me no errors but I can't see anything in store in firebase.

Comment: I added JavaScript on my post, so you can see how it looks like now.